# Using Socketio inside mongoose middleware

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

**I'm trying to use SocketIo inside mongoose middleware, and I declared the io instance inside global but I got undefine inside mongoose middleware**

> app.js

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)

global.io = socketio(server)
```

> profile.js

```
profileSchema.post('save', async function () {
const profile = this

if (profile.isModified('energy')) {
    io.emit('energy', profile.energy)
}

})
```

Comment: I think it might be better if you don't write on top of global but export it, and require inside profile.js or where ever you need

Comment: @Halil Çakar I did it as you told, but I got "Accessing non-existent property 'io' of module exports inside circular dependency"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aight let's make it :)

// config.js

```js
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)

const io = socketio(server);
module.exports = { io }
```

on top of server.js

```
const { io } = require('./config');

io.on('connection', ...); // your connection
```

again on top of profile.js

```
const { io } = require('./config');

profileSchema.post('save', async function () {
    const profile = this

    if (profile.isModified('energy')) {
        io.emit('energy', profile.energy)
    }
})
```

Hope this works :)